# Lebesgue integral of the difference of two positive functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral

### If $f, g \geq 0$ measurable, then $\int f-g = \int f -\int g$

Is this always true or does it need a special condition to hold?

I know if we have addition this holds ($\int f+g = \int f +\int g$)

if $f, g$ measurable, there exist two increasing sequences of simple functions that converges to $f$ and $g$ respectively and their sum is also an increasing sequence of simple functions that converges to $f  +g$

This method wouldn't work when I have a difference of two functions, but I still saw this hold sometimes.

p.s.
It's from the proof of dominated convergence theorem.
This is the last few lines of the proof from the lecture.

$\lim \int|f-f_n|=0$

$|\int f- \int f_n|=|\int f-f_n| \leq \int|f-f_n| \rightarrow0$

therefore 
$\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$

Comment: You'll need $g$ to be integrable so you don't end up with $\infty -\infty$.

Comment: Agree with User8128 - at least one of f and g need to be integrable to avoid indeterminate forms.

Comment: First, for the first line take $f=1-1/x$, $g=1/x$, on $x\in (0,1)$$(*)$, and Lebesgue measure. Second, in DCT we have $|f_n|\leq g$, $g$ is bounded, then case like $(*)$ do no occur.

Comment: Edit: $f=1+1/x$